# Merge Logo Into Simple QRCode (Laravel 5)

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, qr-code

I'm using https://www.simplesoftware.io/docs/simple-qrcode to generate QR code with laravel 5. I want to add a logo at the centre of the qr code since it's doable (according to this plugin) however part of the output was something like this:

j�W�X�"(�@��E 4=*��X  w�`���M�X�"(�@��E`G��=5y��'��wX���I�C��E P,�bu� {?��ݻ�����Ò��"(�@��E P,��WX-�Vm\VWF��qb��'B���@�X�"(�@����T������L��M��꽾�Q�m�#- r�h�����ly*"#{��������bQe_��Z]]��ko����G7EDT�i4TH�,}����t��������ŷ�n�������Q�啵�����R�F�m� �(��|x����*�ny%����*�����UQU�5)U˾+���lUX���k��L=��O��kyemv�X��h�D�L$s>� L����L�$�9������$��(�\a�幂 ��ů�U�qK%��D�P��N��D3���$K��ʣ��#�Օ���i2s����nT��a�I㲎��7+)*AG�H�>�;�$��KMT���J�<|����p��;�K7��!��*<.*'N���7��>�%�ɮs:AMLD-����3J�䃭?�

Here is my code:

```
{!! QrCode::format('png')->merge('https://www.seeklogo.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/facebook-icon-preview-1.png', .3, true)->size(200)->generate('http://www.simplesoftware.io'); !!}
```

Anyone experience with this kindly help me out, your help is appreciated! :)

Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are seeing the raw output of a PNG image.  You will need to base64 encode the image and then place it within an img tag like this:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64, {!! base64_encode(QrCode::format('png')->merge('https://www.seeklogo.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/facebook-icon-preview-1.png', .3, true)->size(200)->generate('http://www.simplesoftware.io');) !!} ">
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not return file by blade. In your controller you should have something like:

```
$response = Response::make($file);
$response->header('Content-Type', "image/png");
return $response;
```